# Ajax duplicating results in each call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple pagination in ajax:

more.js:

```
$(function() {
    $(".showmf").click(function(){  
        var info = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/more.php",
            dataType: 'html',
            data: info,
            success: function(data){
                $(".showmf").remove();
                $('.appdataf').append(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

more.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/more.js"></script>
<?php
echo"<div class='appdataf'>";   
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
   echo"$i";
}
echo"<span class='showmf'>MORE</span>"; 
echo"</div>";
?>
```

First time I click in span it is ok: 1 2 3 4 5

2 time it returns 2 requests: 1 2 3 4 5 more 1 2 3 4 5

3 time it returns 3 requests: 1 2 3 4 5 more 1 2 3 4 5 more 1 2 3 4 5

and so on...

What is wrong that ajax is repeating the PHP `for` many times?

Comment: with append the data will keep on appending to the existing data. if you don't want existing data first clear it in ajax success

Comment: Your ajax is fine just replace $('.appdataf').append(data); with $('.appdataf').html(data);

Comment: @RickJoe Please mark one of answer to finishing this discussion.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery append add content to end of selector content.

You must empty it content like this:

```
$('.appdataf').empty().append(data);
```

Or set data to it html like this:

```
$('.appdataf').html(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because when you load (Even by Ajax) `more.php` file it will also load the `more.js` file (you can check it in fire bug).

Because you wrote `<script type="text/javascript" src="/more.js"></script>` in `more.php`.

And that is re-bind click event to `$(".showmf")` (every time you call the Ajax)

**Solution**

remove this code `<script type="text/javascript" src="/more.js"></script>` 
from `more.php` and put it where it won't load when you call it in Ajax

Comment: oh, you understand my question! So I don't need to wrote the script in php to keeping clicking in the span? how does this re-bind works?

Comment: yes, you don't need to but you must load more.js file when page load first time.
javascript allow bind multiple function in single event so every time you write  $(".showmf").click(function(){..}) it bind click event to $(".showmf") object and perform the execution.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('.appdataf').append(data);
```

appends the result everytime. You need to clear it first before updating it.

```
$('.appdataf').html("");
 $('.appdataf').append(data);
```

or you can directly do  `$('.appdataf').html(data);`

Comment: a jquery object does not have a property `innerHTML` - use `.empty()` to clear it and `.html()` to replace html content in it!

Comment: @Jamiec <div class='appdataf'>, so it is a div. Hence will have an innerHTML

Comment: Yes, but you're referencing a jQuery object not a DOM object, so, trust me, this will not work - go try it if you dont believe me

Comment: @Jamiec oh, ok. I mixed JS and jQuery. Edited the answer,